# Is there any clear difference between event and state

Tags: statechart, scxml

This question is a bit philosophical and is like "data and code are the same thing or not".

Is there any clear difference between event (signal) and state?

Example:

For example, there is a car passing by the road. When the car horns, a man (`man_A`) crossing the road stops suddenly. Horn is the signal, "`man_A` stops suddenly" is the state of `man_A`.

Another man (`man_B`) was crossing the road too at the same time, at the same place.

Let's consider that `man_B` was deaf, so he can't hear the horn. But realizing "`man_A` stopped suddenly" would be a signal for him. He would stop suddenly as if he heard the horn.

<del>So I would say "A state could be a signal for another process. A signal puts a process another state. That's why they are exactly the same thing"</del>

<del>Am I wrong, is there a clear difference between them?</del>

A signal is a state change. We may define any signal with two states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a state is not a signal because a signal comes at a certain specific point in time.

A state-**change** is a result of a signal and can be seen as a signal by itsself. But it is not the state itsself. The state continues to be after the signal is long gone.

How would the initial state be a signal, for example.

Comment: So, we can say "a signal is a state change", so "there are 2 states needed to define a signal".

Comment: It is still the other way around: a signal **causes** a state change. So if you observe the change of the state you realize the signal has been send

Answer (score 1):

They are very, very different:

- The same event may cause transitions to different states, depending on the current state:
  [image: Three states with transitions between them, triggered by the same event]
- In SCXML you can have `<parallel>` states defining orthogonal regions. In this case a single event may trigger multiple simultaneous transitions to different states:
  [image]
- Further, due to the possible presence of `cond="…"` attributes, a transition to another state may or may **not** occur when triggered by a an event. So now we have an event that might not change state.
- Further, it is possible to have a transition with no `event` attribute, causing a state change as soon as some data model value or script result is right. So now we have a state change that can take place with no triggering event.